# Is there a way to hide assets from users within my Mac App?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

I have developed a simple app for Mac which uses a browser window to display some content. Now the assets (images etc.) are visible to anyone who receives the app and discloses the content in finder using 'show package content'.
Is there a way to prevent this? Can I hide it or encapsulate it somehow using code or some XCode function?

Comment: Can you maybe name them starting with a period? (not on a Mac to test this right now).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A trivial way would be to change the extension on your files so the system doesn't recognize them as images. You'd then have to load the images as data and convert them to images in code, which would be a bit of a pain.

A more rigorous solution would be to encrypt the images in your app bundle, then write a utility function that loads and decrypts images.

Comment: Removing the extension will only make it more difficult for humans - the system will still open those files and display them correctly if you e.g. double click on them.

Comment: I suggested *changing* the extension to another file type, which would confuse the system about the type of data contained in the files. (It's not a great solution, as it's trivial to bypass if you know the original filetype.)

Comment: Ok ... changing name and extension will confuse but not change the file's magic number, but note, mine's just a comment, I agree with your solution.

Comment: Now that I think of it, here's another suggestion - why not put the assets in some zipped file. That will hide a lot. Also, you can encrypt the zip and here tooling is no issue as it would be if you roll the encryption yourself.

Comment: @skaak that's not a bad idea. You might want to post that as another answer. Would you have the app open the zip file(s) in memory, or save them somewhere? If you unzip to disk then users could find the unzipped contents. If you unzip in memory then you'd need enough memory to hold all the unzipped contents, or you'd need to break your contents into multiple zip files that were small enough to fit in memory.

Comment: Depends on the assets, if possible just in memory. The moment you unzip you have trouble again. Thanks I'll post ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option.

You can zip all the assets. Use whatever is easiest e.g. pkzip or gzip or even just tar it all. Then you hide a lot of info and, if you want to go the extra step, it is easy to encrypt the zipped file and there are lots of libraries around to include in your project and use to unzip it with.

It should be easy to read assets directly from the zipped file, but if you need them individually you could e.g. put a single file / resource inside a zip or you could unzip it. You could even unzip to temporary space and remove it all when the app quits if you have really sensitive stuff that is too big to fit in memory.

** EDIT **

Java works this way right. A jar file is just a renamed zip and it often contains all of the resources the app needs, and it seems to be working there. So if that is a guide performance should not be too bad.